# Re-use raid 5 in debian that was created in an external raid cabinet

Tags: raid, software-raid

I had 5 disks in a Deltaco raid cabinet configured to run the disk in RAID5.

Now the cabinet doesn't work anymore, and I'm trying to get the data from the disks.

I hoped that I could just pop the disk into a debian-server and re-create the RAID5 with mdadm, but `mdadm --examine /dev/sd*` says `No md superblock detected on` on my 5 disks that was use for the raid.

Anyone have any ideas for other software RAIDs or something I can do?

Comment: Have a look whenever you can extract the RAID controller from that cabinet and if it still works. Hardware RAIDs have a history of being somewhat vendor/controller specific (from what I know). Alternatively restore your backup if you have one?

Comment: I've opened the cabinet up and looked around a little bit, just to see if there was a fuse or something that was broken, but didn't see anything obvious that was wrong.
Haven't have the time to try to extract the RAID controller, might work with another PSU, maybe I will try that.

No, no backup, the data isn't that important.

But it would be nice to be able to restore it.